# Creating a very simple cannon simulator. Occasionally getting a negative x velocity

Tags: java, math

```
xVel = velocity * Math.cos(angle);
yVel = velocity * Math.sin(angle);
```

This is what I use to convert a single initial velocity to x and y velocity, using the angle input by the user. Occasionally the `xVel` will be negative. I was wondering if using an absolute value `Math` function would be fine or would it mathematically skew my results.

This is what I was thinking for that:

```
xVel = velocity * Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
```

Programming in Java BTW, even though that doesn't really matter in this case.

EDIT: Due to a lack of some important information I will add some revisions.
Occasionally I will enter a value for an angle that is in the positive quadrant (i.e. 15°) and still get a negative xVel.
Also this program is assuming that the angle is being counted up from the x axis in a counter clockwise fashion.

Comment: if you're getting a negative answer you need to tell us for which _input values_ that's occurring.

Comment: Are you converting your angle to radians? `Math.cos` needs the angle in radians. `radians = Math.PI * (angle in degrees) / 180`.

Comment: Having made the same mistake before myself, my money's on JohnPS explanation. You should just use Math.toDegrees() though!

Comment: @Baqueta - Yes, java isn't my first language, lol. `Math.toRadians()` is the function to convert degrees to radians.

Comment: @JohnPS Well, I suppose `Math.toRadians()` would be the one to use if you actually wanted to fix the issue... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting a negative x velocity for a 15 degree angle because Math.cos and Math.sin accept the angle in radians and not degrees.

You must first convert your angle in degrees to an angle in radians like this:

```
xVel = velocity * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
yVel = velocity * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just wondering how do you define your coordinate system and get the angle. It's extremely reasonable to get negative value for XVel if your angle is in the second quadrant.

Comment: I am not necessarily restricting it to be positive, but occasionally I get a negative xVel from an angle such as 15°.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a vector, and a vector has direction, as well as size, denoted by the angle.

If you do not care which direction the movement is being made in the relevant axis [right or left/up or down], you can use an absolute value. The sign [minus/plus] you get actually [and only] indicate left/right and up/down

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply check that your angle is between 0 and PI/2. You'll the have positive values for both velocities. How is this angle entered by the user?

Answer (score 0):

If they are firing a cannon at an angle of `90 degrees < angle < 270 degrees` then your x co-ordinate will be negative. They are in fact firing backwards if this is the case.

There are a few ways to restrict this, but I would recommend preventing them from rotating past 90 degrees if you want to enforce a forwards angle.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Out , Hope You Can Figure It , It's ActionSctipt

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/04/28/create-a-flash-artillery-game-step-1/

Comment: Thank you. I have never worked with ActionScript, but it looks easily decipherable. My intentions aren't exactly to make a game, but the code is very useful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The sign of cosinus and sinus of the same angle is not always positive(or negative) on both of functions. As long as you are using the function in scientifical context (such as formulas) you should verify if you aren't getting a right result yet?

In science, a vector of velocity can have a value less than zero.